# query with join across multiple databases-syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 databases namely db1,db2. I need a query that fetch the data from these dbs(db1,db2) which have inturn 2 tables(concessions,invoicing) each.

In db1.concessions => concession is primary key.
   db1.invoicing   => [Concession Number] is primary key

similarly in db2.concessions => concession is primary key.
             db2.invoicing   => [Concession Number] is primary key

**In database1**

db1.tbl1 =>  Concessions table has data

```
    concession
    TH-123
    TH-456
    FP-789
    NZ-609
```

db1.tbl2 =>  invoicing table has data

```
    [Concession Number]          invoiced_on
    TH-322                        10.09.10
    TH-900                        23.10.10
    FP-675                        04.05.09
    NZ-111                        19.11.08
```

luckily, in a database the value of concession in unique. i.e concessions.[concession] = invoicing.[concession Number] yields no data..

**In database2:**

db1.tbl1 =>  Concessions table has data

```
    concession
    TH-123
    FP-789
    NZ-999
    TH-900
```

db1.tbl2 =>  invoicing table has data

```
    [Concession Number]          invoiced_on(dd.mm.yy)
    TH-456                        18.01.06
    TH-777                        23.10.04
    FP-675                        03.05.09
    NZ-149                        26.11.08
```

HEre in db2 concession is unique, concessions.[concession] = invoicing.[concession Number] yields no data..

Now the query should fetch the records that have common 
db1.(concessions.concession OR invoicing.concession number) = db2(concessions.concession OR invoicing.concession number)

In the sample data it should return, TH-123,FP-789,NZ-999, FP-675.

**My 2nd** question is there is possibility of extending this query to multiple database. I can't change the count of databases to 1 as they are already **fixed**. Please let me know the best procedure for the same.

I tried something like this, there are syntax errors,

```
SELECT a.concession as db1_CON_NUMBER FROM db1.dbo.concessions as a  UNION 
SELECT b.[Concession Number] as db1_CON_NUMBER  FROM db1.dbo.invoicing as b 
INNER JOIN 
SELECT c.concession as db2_CON_NUMBER FROM db2.dbo.concessions as c  UNION 
SELECT d.[Concession Number] as db2_CON_NUMBER  FROM db2.dbo.invoicing as d 
ON db1_CON_NUMBER = db2_CON_NUMBER
```

Hope you will answer both the questions.
Thanks for your patience in reading such a long mail!

Comment: just prefix the table with the databasename like db1.dbo.tbl1 and use that in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same way. i.e db1.dbo.concessions and db1.dbo.invoicing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference other databases directly if the user has permissions.

```
<database>.<user>.<tablename>
```

Is the full "path" to the database table.

Often you use

```
db1.dbo.tbl1 join db2.dbo.tbl2
```

where dbo is default for database owner, any table not owned by a specific user is owned by dbo by default.

`UPDATE`

To get the query to validate you can expand it to this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT a.concession as db1_CON_NUMBER FROM db1.dbo.concessions as a  
UNION 
SELECT b.[Concession Number] as db1_CON_NUMBER FROM db1.dbo.invoicing as b ) c

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT c.concession as db2_CON_NUMBER FROM db2.dbo.concessions as a 
UNION 
SELECT b.[Concession Number] as db2_CON_NUMBER FROM db2.dbo.invoicing as b ) d

ON db1_CON_NUMBER = db2_CON_NUMBER
```

But I have not had time to check if this would return the right data but you can test.

Comment: I have permissions to all the databases. I have used db1.dbo.concessions and db1.dbo.invoicing in my query. Hope you can help me further in correcting my query.

Comment: The parenthesis around the separate Union statements makes them derived tables that you can join, but you need the surrounding select a to get any data out of the join.

Comment: You are few seconds faster than me:-) Thanku for the reply. One more question is that, can i extend this query for multiple databases(i mean more than 2). Or do i need to consider some extra measures ...

Comment: As long as the pattern does not change you should be able to do that, but using inner join any match need to exist in all databases, if you want to trap any pair from 3 or more databases you need another approach, replacing the join with another Union  and then select all having count > 1.

Answer (score 2):

If the databases are on the same SQL Server instance you can use 3 part naming:

```
database_name.schema_name.object_name
```

[Using Identifiers As Object Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879.aspx)

If the databases are not on the same instance, create a linked server: [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

[Creating Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

> A linked server allows for access to
>   distributed, heterogeneous queries
>   against OLE DB data sources. After a
>   linked server is created, distributed
>   queries can be run against this
>   server, and queries can join tables
>   from more than one data source. If the
>   linked server is defined as an
>   instance of SQL Server, remote stored
>   procedures can be executed.

Comment: Hmm. No need to link servers if the databases are on the same sql instance.

Comment: I really should read the questions a bit more accurately. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from(
SELECT a.concession as db1_CON_NUMBER FROM BABMwork6_5_3108.dbo.concessions as a  
        WHERE (a.manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  a.manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) 
UNION SELECT b.[Concession Number] as db1_CON_NUMBER  FROM BABMwork6_5_3108.dbo.invoicing as b) as tbl1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT c.concession as db2_CON_NUMBER FROM BABMwork6_6_2909.dbo.concessions as c  
        WHERE (c.manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  c.manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) 
UNION SELECT d.[Concession Number] as db2_CON_NUMBER  FROM BABMwork6_6_2909.dbo.invoicing as d ) as tbl2
ON tbl1.[db1_CON_NUMBER] = tbl2.[db2_CON_NUMBER]
```