# SELECTing across multiple DB2 databases in one query

Tags: database, db2

Ive run into the issue where I need to query 2 separate databases(same instance) in one query.
I am used to doing this with mysql, but Im not sure how to do it with DB2.

In mySQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT  user_info.*, game.*   
FROM user_info, second_db.game_stats as game   
WHERE user_info.uid = game.uid
```

So the question is how i translate a query like that into DB2 syntax?

Equivalent of [this](http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-CHP-12-SECT-3.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason why you have the tables in a separate database?  MySQL doesn't support the concept of schemas, because in MySQL a "schema" is the same thing as a "database".  In DB2, a schema is simply a collection of named objects that lets you group them together.

In DB2, a single database is much closer to an entire MySQL server, as each DB2 database can have multiple schemas.  With multiple schemas inside the same database, your query can run more or less unchanged from how it is written.

However, if you really have 2 separate DB2 databases (and, for some reason, don't want to migrate to a single database with multiple schemas):  You can do this by defining a nickname in your first database.

This requires a somewhat convoluted process of defining a wrapper (`CREATE WRAPPER`), a server (`CREATE SERVER`), user mapping(s) (`CREATE USER MAPPING`) and finally the nickname (`CREATE NICKNAME`).  It is generally easiest to do these tasks using the Control Center GUI  because it will walk you through the process of defining each of these.

Comment: would the setup with the wrapper...nickname allow me to access databases in a fashion like <dbname>.<dbuser>.<table> as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076562/query-with-join-across-multiple-databases-syntax-error

Comment: No, you would just use the 2-part name you specify when you create the nickname.  `CREATE NICKNAME <schema>.<nickname> FOR <dbname>.<dbuser>.<table>`;  then you can just `SELECT * FROM <schema>.<nickname>`.