# MySQL How to join two table in two different database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have two database `chinmay235` and `desarrollo_forum`

I want to join two table `nuke_follow_votes` and `smf_members` using JOIN query.

`nuke_follow_votes` table exist in `chinmay235` and `smf_members` exist in `desarrollo_forum` database.

Code :

```
<?php
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuname = "chinmay_db";
  $dbpass = "2014@movie";
  $dbname = "chinmay235";

  mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuname,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM chinmay235.nuke_follow_votes a LEFT JOIN desarrollo_forum.smf_members b ON a.user_id=b.id_member WHERE b.user_id IS NOT NULL;") or die(mysql_error());
  $res=mysql_fetch_row($qry);

  echo "Total Record = ".mysql_num_rows($qry);
?>
```

***Output*** :

```
SELECT command denied to user 'chinmay235'@'localhost' for table 'smf_members'
```

I am successfully connect the `chinmay235` and getting the table `nuke_follow_votes` but problem is unable to connect the second database.

Please help me how can i connect and join this two table and get the data correct data.

Comment: As stated in the error message, you don't have the priviledges required

Comment: Is yours user authorized to do selects of the table 'smf_members'

Comment: @Dinistro Yes authorize my table `smf_members`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076562/query-with-join-across-multiple-databases-syntax-error

Answer (score 1):

This is just a permission issue.

It seems your user can't select table on the database desarrollo_forum.

Check the permissions for your user with the following command.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'chinmay235'@'localhost';
```

You can add grants with the [GRANT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Same error message coming here. Could you please briefly explain me about your `GRANTS` query

Comment: grant full privileges to user using **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON desarrollo_forum.* TO chinmay235@host**;

Comment: Check the page I sent. There are some examples there. Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Server allows you to join tables from different databases as long as those databases are on the same server. The join syntax is the same; the only difference is that you must fully specify table names.

Let's suppose you have two databases on the same server - Db1 and Db2. Db1 has a table called Clients with a column ClientId and Db2 has a table called Messages with a column ClientId (let's leave asside why those tables are in different databases).

Now, to perform a join on the above-mentioned tables you will be using this query:

**Assuming the account has appropriate permissions you can use:**

```
    SELECT ...
  FROM A.table t1
  JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

Comment: Why are you answering for SQL Server when OP has tagged MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for join two tables

`SELECT <select_list>
FROM Table A.A
JOIN Table B.B
ON A.key = B.key`

As per your requirement you can use LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN,INNER JOIN

Comment: This is working for single database. But my requirement is how can i fetch data in two different database using Join query. Please read my questio again..

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
LEFT JOIN [DB2].[MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable] tab2
ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID`

Answer (score 0):

The query seems fine but have you limited the select privilege of desarrollo_forum db?

Try to give privilege to the second db like this,

```
GRANT ALL ON desarrollo_forum.* TO chinmay235@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```